# Using query parameter of type not supported in Spring Data JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, type-conversion, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I tried to write a query method in my repository similar to this

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE foo SET some_timestamp = :someTimestamp WHERE id = :id")
void updateSomeTimestamp(@Param("id") long id, @Param("someTimestamp") Instant someTimestamp)
```

When executing the code I got the following error:

*org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.time.Instant. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.*

Did I forget something or is usage of Instant as parameter simply not supported by Spring Data Jdbc? If so, is such a support planned in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data JDBC has no knowledge of the type expected by the SQL-statement. Therefore it passes parameters a long without any conversion and relies on the database to properly handle the parameter.

One might argue that it should convert parameters if a matching converter is registered, but this is currently not the case.

Therefore currently the solution is to convert the argument yourself and changing the argument type to `java.util.Date` or whatever your JDBC driver is accepting.

Comment: I understand your point but from my opinion java.time.* is a set of classes that should be supported out of the box.

Comment: I kind of agree and would make that case against the JDBC driver. The question is: Should Spring Data JDBC try to convert parameters?

Comment: According to the documentation (at least for postgresql-drive which we use) some classes from java.time are supported, Instant being not included. => https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html
In my opinion converting parameters from java.time.* to some jdbc-compatible type would be a nice feature I guess more users of Spring Data JDBC would benefit from.

Comment: I created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-464 for this.

Answer (score 3):

For those who came here looking for a solution to generate `java.sql.Timestamp` instances with better than millisecond precision (the `Timestamp` constructor that accepts nanos is deprecated):

`Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());`

This assumes your operating system supports better than millisecond precision for the system clock.  It's useful for databases that support better-than-millisecond TIMESTAMP precision, such as with PostgreSQL, which supports microsecond precision.

You can convert it back to an `Instant` or `LocalDateTime`:

`System.out.println(timestamp.toInstant()); // UTC`

or

`System.out.println(timestamp.toLocalDateTime()); // local time`

I will also reiterate information stoetti provided in a comment, that according to the documentation link that stoetti provided, 
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html, the PostgreSQL JDBC driver does recognize the following `java.time` classes as timestamps:

`java.time.LocalTime` as `TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]`

`java.time.LocalDateTime` as `TIMESTAMP [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]`

`java.time.OffsetDateTime` as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`

But not `java.time.Instant`, as stoetti pointed out.